# Failed to produce diagnostic for expression for image array

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I am trying to utilize the UIImage array in SWiftUI class for forEach loop but Xcode always gives me the error 'Failed to produce diagnostic for expression;'. I also tried using the *Data* array but same error. Below is my code. It will be great if someone can point what I am doing wrong?

```
struct Sample: View {

    let imageArray: [UIImage]

    var body: some View {
        ForEach(imageArray) { image in
            Image(uiImage: image)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you have to initialize your array, such as "var imageArray: [UIImage] = []" for an empty array. If you want some UIImage in it, you need to put them in.

Comment: @workingdog, not if it is being passed in as part of initialisation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem by adding ***id*** in ForEach loop. Below is how my code looks now.

```
struct ImageData: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let image: UIImage
}

struct Sample: View {

    let imageDataArray: [ImageData]

    var body: some View {
        ForEach(imageDataArray) { imageData in
            Image(uiImage: imageData.image)
        }
    }
}
```

What I learned from here is, for objects such as UIImage, if you need to enumerate, you must add id property on the ForEach loop. To solve the problem, I created a model class containing id and image property and enumerated it.

Comment: If ImageDate is `Identifiable`, you don't need the `id:` parameter in `ForEach`

Answer (score 0):

The ForEach operator requires elements of the array to conform to identifiable. For something like UIImage, you can just pass self.

```swift
var body: some View {
    ForEach(imageArray, id: \.self) { image in
        Image(uiImage: image)
    }
}
```

Personally, I would also wrap it in a Stack, just to be explicit

```swift
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        ForEach(imageArray, id: \.self) { image in
            Image(uiImage: image)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you forgot the "id: \.self" in the ForEach.

Comment: @workingdog Thanks, got lost in translation.

Answer (score 0):

this works for me:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct TestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
struct Sample: View {
    let imageArray: [UIImage]
    
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(imageArray, id: \.self) { image in
            Image(uiImage: image)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var imageArray: [UIImage] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        Sample(imageArray: imageArray)
            .onAppear {
                if let img = UIImage(systemName: "globe") {
                    imageArray.append(img)
                }
            }
    }
}
```